# asp.net core 2.1 ef core 2.1 date compare not working on server

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

Hi there I am facing a very strange issue in asp.net core 2.1 
I have a query selecting some data for a specific date like

```
var balances = dbContext.Balances.Where(x => x.BalanceDate.Date == workDay.Date);
```

But the query is working on local ENV and even when i connect to remote SQL server. but on Server side it doesn't return any results.

Comment: Is your Remote SQL Server set to run in a different Time i.e., UTC time?

Comment: Is the connection string the same?  You could be accessing a different database that doesn't contain the same data.

Comment: @jdweng There is only 1 database with data :)

Comment: Are you sure you do not have more than on mdf file?

Comment: @jdweng Yes 100% sure.

Comment: Hi @Umang I think comparing only date part with '.Date' will ignore the time part ?
the time on the system is same as my local env which is utc+00:00 Dublin,Edinburgh, London time. Sql server is saving date in 2018-07-16 16:04:38 +milseconds time format.

Comment: Interesting. Where is your server hosted? Is it azure web app by any chance?

Comment: it is a custom vps with Windows server 2012 from 1&1.co.uk 
no idea why its doing this.

Comment: Can you confirm that timezone for your server is same as your local timezone? It is very interesting if local and remote servers are in same timezone and giving you different results

Comment: @Umang Yes they are identical UTC 00 with day light saving

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with timezone or milliseconds included in the DateTime type in SQL Server. It can be one of the reasons above, You can do this (`==` comparison only)

```
 var balances = dbContext.Balances.Where(x => 
     x.BalanceDate./*Date.*/Year == workDay/*.Date*/.Year &&
     x.BalanceDate./*Date.*/Month == workDay/*.Date*/.Month &&
     x.BalanceDate./*Date.*/Day == workDay/*.Date*/.Day);
```

PS: It's always a good practice to manage/unitialize the timezone offset, or use UTC when dealing with date types.

Comment: I 'll give it a try but not sure why its happening